# How can I register a (boundless) type hierarchy using Autofac?

Tags: autofac

I've got a Factory interface (along with concrete implementations):

```
// foo.dll
interface IFooProvider
{
    T GetFoo<T>()
        where T : BaseFoo;
}
```

My BaseFoo is not abstract, but only its subclasses are actually useful:

```
// shared.dll
class BaseFoo
{ ... }
```

I've also got a (potentially unbounded) number of subclasses of `BaseFoo` across many assemblies:

```
// foo.dll
class AFoo : BaseFoo
{ ... }

// foo2.dll
class BFoo : BaseFoo
{ ... }

... and many more ...
```

Naively, I had been registering the `Foo`-derived classes in an unsurprising way:

```
// foo.dll
class ConcreteFooRegistration : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // a concrete FooProvider is registered elsewhere

        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IFooProvider>().GetFoo<AFoo>());
        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IFooProvider>().GetFoo<BFoo>());
        ...
    }
}
```

But this implies that:

1. the assembly containing `ConcreteFooRegistration` (e.g. foo.dll) *also* contains some/all of `AFoo`, `BFoo`, etc.
2. the assembly containing `ConcreteFooRegistration` (e.g. foo.dll) *references* the assemblies (e.g. foo2.dll) containing some/all of `AFoo`, `BFoo`, etc.
3. `IFooProvider` be available to any *other* assembly containing `BaseFoo`-derived classes and the `Module` that registers them

**For sake of discussion, assume that none of these is possible and/or desirable.** That is, I'm looking for solutions other than "move `IFooProvider` into shared.dll".

Since `AFoo` and `BFoo` are the real dependencies that other types are interested in, and `IFooProvider` is (from that perspective) just an instantiation detail, I got inspired by [the Autofac+Serilog integration](https://github.com/nblumhardt/autofac-serilog-integration) that Nicholas came up with. I've used a similar approach elsewhere, so I wrote up an `AttachToComponentRegistration()` implementation:

```
// foo.dll
class ConcreteFooRegistration : Module
{
    // NOTICE: there's no Load() method
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(...)
    {
        ...
        registration.Preparing += (sender, e) =>
        {
          var pFoo = new ResolvedParameter(
              (p, i) => p.ParameterType.IsAssignableTo<BaseFoo>(),
              (p, i) => i.Resolve<IFooProvider>().GetFoo<FooWeNeed>()
          );
          e.Parameters = new [] { pFoo }.Concat(e.Parameters);
        };
    }
}
```

This was successful, in that I was able to **remove all** the individual `BaseFoo`-derived registrations from `ConcreteFooRegistration` and still successfully resolve **arbitrary** `BaseFoo`-derived dependencies with constructor injection:

```
// other.dll:
class WorkerRegisteration : Module
{
   protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
   {
       builder.RegisterType<Worker>();
       // NOTICE: FooYouDidntKnowAbout is NOT explicitly registered
   }
}

class Worker
{
   public Worker(FooYouDidntKnowAbout foo)
   { ... }

   ...
}
```

**BUT:** now I can't arbitrarily resolve `AFoo` outside of constructor injection:

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
    // here's one use for a BaseFoo outside constructor injection
    var foo = c.Resolve<AFoo>();
    if (foo.PropValue1)
        return new OtherClass(foo.PropValue2);
    else
        return new YetAnother(foo.PropValue3);
}
...
builder.Register(c =>
{
    // here's another
    var foo = c.Resolve<AFoo>();
    return c.Resolve(foo.TypePropValue);
});
```

Assuming that publishing `IFooProvider` as a public export of foo.dll or moving it to shared.dll is undesirable/impossible, thus eliminating the naive-but-unsurprising implementation above, (how) can I set up my registrations to be able to resolve arbitrary subclasses of `BaseFoo` from anywhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I think what you're looking for is a registration source.** A registration source is a dynamic "registration provider" you can use to feed Autofac registrations as needed.

As of this writing, [the doc on registration sources is pretty thin](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html) (I just haven't gotten a chance to write it) but there's [a blog article](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/declarative-context-adapters-autofac2/) with some details about it.

**Registration sources are how Autofac supports things like `IEnumerable<T>` or `Lazy<T>`** - we don't require you actually register every collection, instead we dynamically feed the registrations into the container using sources.

Anyway, let me write you up a sample here and maybe I can use it later to massage it into the docs, eh? :)

First, let's define a very simple factory and implementation. I'm going to use "Service" instead of "Foo" here because my brain stumbles after it sees "foo" too many times. That's a "me" thing. But I digress.

```
public interface IServiceProvider
{
    T GetService<T>() where T : BaseService;
}

public class ServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
{
    public T GetService<T>() where T : BaseService
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

OK, now let's make the service types. Obviously for this sample all the types are sort of in one assembly, but when your code references the type and the JIT brings it in from some other assembly, it'll work just the same. Don't worry about cross-assembly stuff for this.

```
public abstract class BaseService { }
public class ServiceA : BaseService { }
public class ServiceB : BaseService { }
```

Finally, a couple of classes that consume the services, just so we can see it working.

```
public class ConsumerA
{
    public ConsumerA(ServiceA service)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsumerA: {0}", service.GetType());
    }
}


public class ConsumerB
{
    public ConsumerB(ServiceB service)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsumerB: {0}", service.GetType());
    }
}
```

Good.

**Here's the important bit, now: the registration source.** The registration source is where you will:

1. Determine if the resolve operation is asking for a `BaseService` type or not. If it's not, then you can't handle it so you'll bail.
2. Build up the dynamic registration for the specific type of `BaseService` derivative being requested, which will include the lambda that invokes the provider/factory to get the instance.
3. Return the dynamic registration to the resolve operation so it can do the work.

It looks like this:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Core;
using Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate;
using Autofac.Core.Lifetime;
using Autofac.Core.Registration;

public class ServiceRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(
        Service service,
        Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        var swt = service as IServiceWithType;
        if(swt == null || !typeof(BaseService).IsAssignableFrom(swt.ServiceType))
        {
            // It's not a request for the base service type, so skip it.
            return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();
        }

        // This is where the magic happens!
        var registration = new ComponentRegistration(
            Guid.NewGuid(),
            new DelegateActivator(swt.ServiceType, (c, p) =>
            {
                // The factory method is generic, but we're working
                // at a reflection level, so there's a bit of crazy
                // to deal with.
                var provider = c.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
                var method = provider.GetType().GetMethod("GetService").MakeGenericMethod(swt.ServiceType);
                return method.Invoke(provider, null);
            }),
            new CurrentScopeLifetime(),
            InstanceSharing.None,
            InstanceOwnership.OwnedByLifetimeScope,
            new [] { service },
            new Dictionary<string, object>());

        return new IComponentRegistration[] { registration };
    }

    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents { get{ return false; } }
}
```

It looks complex, but it's not too bad.

The last step is to get the factory registered as well as the registration source. For my sample, I put those in an Autofac module so they're both registered together - it doesn't make sense to have one without the other.

```
public class ServiceProviderModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceProvider>().As<IServiceProvider>();
        builder.RegisterSource(new ServiceRegistrationSource());
    }
}
```

**Finally, let's see it in action.** If I throw this code into a console app...

```
static void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<ConsumerA>();
    builder.RegisterType<ConsumerB>();
    builder.RegisterModule<ServiceProviderModule>();
    var container = builder.Build();

    using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var a = scope.Resolve<ConsumerA>();
        var b = scope.Resolve<ConsumerB>();
    }
}
```

What you end up with on the console is:

```
ConsumerA: ServiceA
ConsumerB: ServiceB
```

Note I had to register my *consuming classes* but I didn't explicitly register any of the `BaseService`-derived classes - that was all done by the registration source.

**If you want to see more registration source samples, check out the Autofac source**, [particularly under the `Autofac.Features` namespace](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/tree/c9b56b7737df387afa667a6833b9d6100f6100be/src/Autofac/Features). There you'll find [things like the `CollectionRegistrationSource`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/c9b56b7737df387afa667a6833b9d6100f6100be/src/Autofac/Features/Collections/CollectionRegistrationSource.cs), which is responsible for handling `IEnumerable<T>` support.

Comment: This is sensational - thank you very much! I had a feeling it was something like this; I even had a look at the `DelegateActivator` but wasn't sure how to work with it.